# Regarding IP subnetting process

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

Professor taught the following scenario. An organization has purchased a Class-C address  `216.21.5.0` and would like to use it to address its offices at Arizona, Florida and California. It has the following network setup.

[image]

So, the total number of networks required is 5. So, subnet mask would be 255.255.255.224 or /27. Also, the lowest subnet bit was 32 and hence the increment value would be 32. So, we get a total of 8 network ranges as follows.

```
216.21.5.0 to 31
216.21.5.32 to 63
216.21.5.64 to 95
216.21.5.96 to 127
216.21.5.128 to 159
216.21.5.160 to 191
216.21.5.192 to 223
216.21.5.224 to 255
```

Thus, we get approximately 30 computers under each network range. That is, 30 in Arizona office, 30 in California office and 30 in Florida office.

Now, about my doubt.

1. If we do the network subnetting as above, we are wasting large amounts of IP addresses for the intermediate links that do not have any systems connected to them.
2. Also, if there are (say)90 computers in Arizona office and only 20 computers in Florida office, then according to this method, that would be impossible.

P.S. I'm very confused with this IP subnetting process. Please clear my doubts. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to comment on the "approximately 30 computers under each network range". Is that 30 computers, **plus** a few printers, a scanner, a few mobile devices etc etc? Computers are not the only things who want one of more IPs.

Comment: Also, in nitpicking mode: Class C networks are gone. I understand that you have a /24, but nobody except Cisco still uses classfull networking. [CIRD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) is the new thing and it has been around since 1993 (that is 20 years!).

Comment: @Hennes 30 computers was just arbitrary. Guess, I should've said 30 systems. And I know about CIRD, but our syllabus includes even the retro stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's long since outdated. I remember back in something like 2002 when the company I worked for then was allocated an IPv4 /28. Better to just say /24 if that's what you mean; everyone who is seriously into networking will know exactly what it means, and no one will need to go into nitpicking mode @Hennes.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I have a doubt. It may sound silly, but still. Why does a company buy so many ip addresses, instead of just buying one address and performing DHCP/NAT with private addresses. I believe this would save a lot?

Comment: They do that because sometimes you actually *need* a large number of publicly routable addresses. Yes, NAT and front-loading proxies and load balancers can do a lot to save on address space, but it doesn't solve everything and it also adds complexity.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling `"sometimes you actually need a large number of publicly routable addresses"` would you please provide an example?

Comment: If you have a large datacenter providing multiple disparate services, you may want (some of) those to be individually addressable on the IP level. Obviously this depends heavily on what you are doing on your part of the Internet; that's the very reason why ISPs allocate large netblocks to some customers and small netblocks to other customers. It isn't (or at least shouldn't be) based on elitism, but reasonably proved need.

Comment: This about this example : You are a web-hosting compagny, and are hosting your client's web servers. You buy for example a /24 network, and charge each client for 1 IP. Associate this IP with the customer's server hosting one web server(s). You can't NAT here, because you would then only be able to address one server on your public adress' port 80 while needeing many. (you can't ask customers to add a custom port when connecting to your website, it's un-professionnal)

Comment: seriously, if your professors scenario is applied in real world, he will got fired i think. there is no point to purchase a class-C subnet for company internal use. Someone suggest that would be $2000/month

Comment: In my point of view, the correct setup should be 3 different 192.168.xxx.xxx subnet (or 10.xxx.xxx.xxx) and then do NAT and VPN tunneling, while total 3 ( 6 including HA resilience gateway)  public ip address is needed.

Comment: you can host multiple site of single ip with port 80 using virtual server, it does not need that number of public ip address. unless you need to "pretend" to be more than 1 company in front of bank, which they actually demand fixed individual ip/port mapping, and they do not accept duplicate. (Thus there is company have 10 public ip address here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. If we do the network subnetting as above, we are wasting large amounts of IP addresses for the intermediate links that do not have any systems connected to them.
> 2. Also, if there are (say)90 computers in Arizona and only 20 computers in Florida, then according to this method, that would be impossible.

The answers to these two questions are basically the same: **you don't have to slice a subnet into equal-size portions.** This is the same as that a single ISP may allocate one customer a /22 and another customer might receive a /28, based on their respective addressing needs.

Let's say your subnet IP address allocation needs are 90, 50 and 30 addresses, respectively, and that you have a full IPv4 /24 (but nothing more) to play with. Let's see how we might allocate those subnets.

90 IP addresses fits nicely within a /25, so you allocate .0/25 for that which leaves you with a nice margin and .128/25 unassigned.

50 IP addresses needs a block of 64 (which translates to a /26), so you allocate .128/26 which leaves you with a bit of a margin and .192/26 unallocated.

30 IP addresses needs a block of 32 (a /27), so you allocate .192/27, which leaves you with almost no margin to grow in but .224/27 remains unallocated. 20 IP addresses would also require a /27 but leave you with a much larger margin. (If on the other hand you needed 35 IP addresses you'd need a /26, which leaves you with no remaining IP address space in your allocated netblock. In that case and if you need to run the point-to-point links within your allocated netblock but outside of the site subnets, you'd have to beg your ISP for a /23 instead and start over.)

The space .224/27 can be subdivided into /30s or /31s for the point-to-point links. Since you only really need two IP addresses (one for each endpoint) on each link, /31s should do, but sometimes a /30 is used to allow for a network and broadcast address as well. If you use /31s, you can squeeze 16 (2^(31-27)) point-to-point links in there without resorting to tricks like NAT or local addresses such as RFC 1918.

Hopefully I got the numbers right (I haven't double-checked), but you get the idea. The trick is to allocate the largest blocks first, and then continue with what remains, allocating the smallest blocks possible that will allow you the number of hosts you need on each subnet.

You might have other issues because absent special arrangements the overall /24 will almost certainly be going to one of the sites, but if you can live with that, a setup like the above should get you pretty close to an ideal (or least-bad) addressing situation.

It's also worth remembering that it's usually a bad idea to allocate a public, global IP address to each client host. Use a single NAT gateway in front of everything that doesn't require direct Internet access, and you can easily consolidate a few hundred clients onto a single global IP address, and in addition likely gain a bit of network security at the same time.

Thanks to [@Kwaio](https://superuser.com/users/239282/kwaio), here's [a diagram illustrating](http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/9007/0qms.png) how such IP address allocations can be done.

Comment: I think this is for educational purposes only of explaining subnetting, but you're right about public addresses and NAT, which he may haven't learned yet. Mind if I make a little schema to add to your post ?

Comment: @Kwaio If you think it'll help clarify the answer, by all means go ahead. I'm not in a position of being able to make any nice diagrams right now. I mention NAT as an aside because it is an address-conserving technique and many applications don't require direct global Internet access.

Comment: I would *really appreciate* if those who have downvoted this can take a moment to explain what's wrong with *my answer* (as opposed to the question, which is an entirely different kettle of fish). It seems to me a perfectly reasonable answer to a somewhat newbie-ish question.

Comment: @Kwaio I'm still a little skeptical, why would our professor teach such a technique which splits the range equally. It feels stupid!

Comment: @VISHNUVIVEK It may be easier to explain, but I agree, it isn't a likely real-world scenario. If you want a real answer to *that* question, though, you'll have to ask your professor. By all means encourage him to have a look at this question and answer, or [the Network Engineering Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). In the meantime, if you feel that this answer properly answers your question, please do accept it. :) (I've seen answers with scores well into negative territory being accepted, believe it or not.)